# PHP Assign Value From Variable to Function

Tags: php, scope

How to assign value to PHP function. I have a code like this :

```
<?php
$val_id = "010105";

function get_news()
{
    $query = mysql_query"SELECT * FROM news WHERE val_id = '$val_id'";
}
```

When I query that function, the value from $val_id can't send to function get_news. So the result is empty.

Please help to solve that. Thanks

Comment: havr you tried placing your varibale inside the function ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a scoping problem. `$val_id` is a global variable, so your function doesn't know about it unless you tell it about it somehow. You have two main options:

- Pass `$val_id` as a parameter (recommended):

```
$val_id = "010105";

function get_news($val_id)
{
    $query = mysql_query"SELECT * FROM news WHERE val_id = '$val_id'";
}

get_news($val_id);
```

- Use `$val_id` as a global (not recommended):

```
$val_id = "010105";

function get_news()
{
    global $val_id;
    $query = mysql_query"SELECT * FROM news WHERE val_id = '$val_id'";
}

get_news();
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to pass `val_id` as a parameter to the function. Try this:

```
<?php
$val_id = "010105";

function get_news($val_id) {
   $query = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM news WHERE val_id = $val_id");
}
```

This is because you set `val_id` outside the function, but it isn't set **inside** the function.

By passing it in the parenthesis, you make it available as a local variable of `get_news()`.

Answer (score 0):

**Try this !**

> get_news("010105");
>
> function get_news($val_id)
>
> {
>
> $query = mysql_query"SELECT * FROM news WHERE val_id = '$val_id'";
>
> }

Answer (score 0):

Allow me to introduce a more mature version.

```
class News
{
    private $value_id;

    public function News($value_id) {
        $this->value_id = $value_id;
    }

    public function get()
    {
        $query = sprintf("SELECT * FROM news WHERE val_id = %d", $this->value_id);
        return mysql_query($query);

    }
}

$news = new News($val_id);
$news->get();
```